# Assigning any list in a list to string script.

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm working on a project from Chapter 4 of Automate the Boring Stuff with Python. Here's the project's prompt:

> "For practice, write programs to do the following tasks. Comma Code
>   Say you have a list value like this: spam = [' apples', 'bananas',
>   'tofu', 'cats'] Write a function that takes a list value as an
>   argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma
>   and a space, with and inserted before the last item. For example,
>   passing the previous spam list to the function would return 'apples,
>   bananas, tofu, and cats'. But your function should be able to work
>   with any list value passed to it."

I wrote a script that creates a list with commas and an 'and' before the last item: But I can't figure out how to make the script work with any list value passed to it. I've tried using the input function to call a list, but that doesn't work (or I can't get to work), since the input function only receives strings and not list names?

Here's the farthest I've gotten:

```
def listToString(list):
    if list[-1]:
        list.append('and '+str(list[-1]))
        list.remove(list[-2])
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print(''+list[i]+', ')

spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
listToString(spam)
```

As far as using the input() function, here's the code I've tried to no avail. I enter the spam list in the shell editor and run this:

```
def listToString(list):
    if list[-1]:
        list.append('and '+str(list[-1]))
        list.remove(list[-2])
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print(''+list[i]+', ')

list = input("What list do you want to use?")
listToString(list)
```

Comment: This function is underspecified. An empty list doesn't have a last element, `['apples']` probably shouldn't become `'and apples'`, and `['apples', 'bananas']` probably shouldn't have a comma in the output.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple solution which only uses syntax already covered by [Chapter 4](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter4/):

```
def toString(arr):
    s = ''
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if i > 0:
            if i == len(arr) - 1:
                # last one
                s = s + ' and '
            else:
                # second, third, ...
                s = s + ', '
        s = s + arr[i];
    return s
```

It works for arrays with any number of elements.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the easiest way is to substitute the last element with "and ...." and then join everything with ", "

```
def merge(list):
  return ', '.join(list[:-1] + ['and '+list[-1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is solely based on basic principles covered up to chapter 4. It makes liberal use of the "end" parameter presented in Chapter 3.

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
print("'", end='')
for i in range(len(spam)-1):
    print(spam[i], end=', ')
print('and '+str(spam[-1]), end='')
print("'")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe "But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it." means that you shouldn't hard code the example list (['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']) in the function.

So, the simplest form of the function would be:

```
def listToString(list):
    return "{} and {}".format(", ".join(list[:-1]]), list[-1])
```

but when you want to process other types than strings and fewer than 2 elements, the function becomes:

```
def listToString(list):
    length = len(list)
    if length == 0 :
        return ""
    elif length == 1 :
        return "{}".format(list[0])
    else:
        strings = ["{}".format(x) for x in list[:-1]]
        return "{} and {}".format(", ".join(strings), list[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
spam = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'second to last', 'last']

def func(listValue):
    print('\'', end='')    # Openning single quote.
    for i in range(len(listValue[:-2])):    # Iterate through all values in the list up to second to last.
        print(str(listValue[i]), end=', ')
        continue
    print(str(listValue[-2]) + ' and ' + str(listValue[-1]) + '\'')    # Add second to last and last to string separated by 'and'. End with a single quote.

listValue = spam
func(listValue)

    # Will do for any list.
```

Output is:

'zero, one, two, three, second to last and last'

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution for this problem. Along with my comments for each line of code.  Hope this helps.

```
 spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

# function should return 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats' 

def listToString(list):

    newString = '' # create an empty string variable 

    # for loop that iterates through length of list 
    for index in range(len(list)):
        # put a comma and space after each word except the last one 
        if index in range(len(list)-1): 
            newString += list[index] + ',' + ' '
        else:
            newString += 'and' + ' ' #put the word and + a space
            #finally put the last word from the list 
            #spam in the string newString
            newString += list[index] 

       #return newString value
       return '{}'.format(newString) 

listToString(spam)
```

Output:

```
'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with after one week of learning python:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats', 'rats', 'turkeys']
group = []
for i in range(len(spam)-1):
    group.append(spam[i])
print (', '.join(group),'& ' +spam[-1])
```

I was just working on this problem today during my new python hobby.

I know my solution isn't quite as compact and elegant as the top one.  I basically just used a for statement to create a second list w/o the last entry, then used print to join that group add the "&" symbol and finally the last item.

Comment: instead of a `for` loop, it'd be simpler to do `print (', '.join(spam[:-1]), '& ' + spam[-1])`, which is essentially the top answer. `spam[:-1]` is the list without the last entry. See [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings), which works the same for strings as for lists. Do ctrl+F and type "Slice".

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
spam.insert(-1, ' and')
print(spam[0] + ', ' + spam[1] + ', ' + spam[2] + ',' + spam[3] + ' ' + spam[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my solution

```
def converter(mylist):
    mystr=''
    if len(mylist)>1:
        for i in range(len(mylist)-1):
            mystr=mystr+str(mylist[i])+', '
        mystr=mystr+'and '+str(mylist[-1])
        print(mystr)
    elif len(mylist)==1:    
        mystr=mystr+str(mylist[0])
        print(mystr)
    else:
        print('Your list is empty')
spam = []
t='1'
while t != '':
    print('Input new value in list (Or enter nothing to stop)')
    t=str(input())
    if t != '':
        spam.append(t)
converter(spam)
```

Answer (score 0):

My version of the Comma Code:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
newList = []
myString = ''

def comma(aList):
    for i in range(len(aList) - 1):
        newList.append(aList[i])
    newList.append('and ')
    myString = ', '.join(newList)
    print(myString + aList[-1])

comma(spam)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the assignment, you must make sure "your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it." That means it must work with 0, 1, 1+ list values.

```
spam = ['green','eggs','ham']

def merge(list):
    if len(list) == 0:
        return None
    elif len(list) == 1:
        return list[0]
    else:
        return ', '.join(list[:-1] + ['and '+list[-1]])

print(merge(spam))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's pretty straightforward solution to the problem:

```
def lst2str(spam):
    str = ''
    for word in spam:
        if word != spam[-1]:
            spacing = word + ", "
            str += spacing
        else:
            spacing = "and " + word
            str += spacing
    return str
```