# Can't get code in shell to work as a program

Tags: python

I am working through the "[Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com)" book and am stuck on one of the practice problems. My solution works in the shell, but not when I try to run it as a program. Here is the problem prompt:

> Say you have a list value like this:
>
> ```
> spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
> ```
>
> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string  with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with and inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam list to the function would return 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'. But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it.

Here is my code:

```
def listToString(usersList):
    myStr = ', '.join(str(i) for i in usersList[0:-1]) # converts all but last list element to string and joins with commas
    myStr = myStr + ' and ' + str(usersList[-1]) # adds on "and", converts  final list element to string and adds to myStr
    print(myStr)

myList = input()
listToString(myList)
```

When I define a list in the shell and run the above steps on it, I get the result I want:

```
'apples, bananas, tofu and cats'
```

But when I try to group the steps together in the above program, the result is this:

```
[, a, p, p, l, e, s, ,,  , b, a, n, a, n, a, s, ,,  , t, o, f, u, ,,  , c, a, t, s and ]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks very much if you've taken the time to read this. There are a couple other topics on this same practice question on SO already ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768758/assigning-any-list-in-a-list-to-string-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824634/automate-the-boring-stuff-with-python-comma-code)), but I was still stuck so I went ahead and posted.

Comment: You need to pass `listToString` an actual list, not a string. `input` (in Python 3) _always_ returns a string.

Comment: The exercise doesn't say that you're supposed to get a list from user input. Just code the `spam` list into your script.

Comment: To all the people telling the OP to convert a string returned by `input` into a list: please read the question! The exercise is to write a function that accepts a _list_. You're adding unnecessary extra complication that's simply not required for this exercise.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns  a string. You need convert the string to list before passing to the function using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
myList = input().split()  # 'apple banana' -> ['apple', 'banana']
```

Otherwise, string is iterated; yielding each character as items.

```
>>> a_string = 'abcd'
>>> for x in a_string:
...     print(x)
...
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem since the `input` you are getting is a string and not a `list`.
First convert the input to a list, then run your function.

Try to use `.split()` on the input.

Answer (score 1):

When take input of the string, make sure the input is "split()",to convert it into a string:

```
def listToString(usersList):
        myStr = ', '.join(str(i) for i in usersList[0:-1]) # converts all but last list element to string and joins with commas
        myStr = myStr + ' and ' + str(usersList[-1]) # adds on "and", converts  final list element to string and adds to myStr
        print(myStr)

myList = input().split(',')
listToString(myList)
```

Input:

```
apples,bananas,tofu,cats
```

Output:

```
apples, bananas, tofu and cats
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to join list as per problem statement details,

```
def listToString(userList):
    return ', '.join(userList[:-1]) + ' and ' + userList[-1]
```

Execution:

```
In [13]: listToString(spam)
Out[13]: 'apples, bananas, tofu and cats'
```

Now when you accept list from user, you are accepting raw string, 
You need to convert it into list.

```
In [16]: mylist = input()
'apples,bananas,tofu,cats'

In [19]: mylist.split(',')
Out[19]: ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

In [20]: userList = mylist.split(',')

In [21]: listToString(userList)
Out[21]: 'apples, bananas, tofu and cats'
```